# Why is unique contraint not working in Ecto?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following in my User model :

```
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:login, :email])
    |> validate_required([:login, :email])
    |> unique_constraint(:login)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end
```

However just setting the unique_contraint this way does not work. I'm still getting duplicate login and email when testing my controller.

I got this working but I had to put the `:unique` keyword argument to `true` in the model schema as well as create a unique index per column in the migration.

Is Ecto not checking the constraint itself in addition to the PostgreSQL unique index ? Is there any point to adding a `unique_constraint` to the `changeset/2` function ?

Answer (score 3):

> The unique constraint works by relying on the database to check if the unique constraint has been violated or not and, if so, `Ecto` converts it into a changeset error.
>   — [`Ecto.Changeset.unique_constraint/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html?#unique_constraint/3)

That said, the reason for `unique_constraint/3` to ever exist is to unify errors (make the changeset error out of what was received from the DB.) That obviously eases and standardizes the error handling.

`Ecto` obviously cannot check the constraint on its own, without relying on DB.

Comment: *Ecto obviously cannot check the constraint on its own, without relying on DB.*

Well Ruby on Rails does a select just to check the unique validations, not relying on DB server errors.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you expect RoR to download 10TB database locally to validate the uniqueness of the value locally? I doubt it does, even despite it would be so _railish_.

Comment: In Ruby on Rails when you set a unique constraint it fires a SQL SELECT to check the unique constraint itself. Ecto does not provide this facility.

Comment: Downloading the data is not necessary the select is just a count().

Comment: Actually I prefer the Ecto way =)

Comment: Ah, I got it. `Ecto` does not provide this because it does not work as expected in the distributed environment. Two concurrent `select` would result in a race condition, and the second attempt to insert would blow up, which makes this check totally meaningless.

Comment: I don't think there is a race condition if you use a transaction.

Comment: Sure there is. Transaction simply makes it even worse. Both `select` return “you are welcome to insert” and then who ran first wins and the other unexpectedly sucks.